# idlpy Import Issue

Tags: python, idl

When I try to import idlpy I get the following ModuleNotFoundError.

My Input:

```
%load_ext idlmagic
import sys
sys.path.append('/Applications/harris/idl88/lib/bridges')
from idlpy import *
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 import sys
      2 sys.path.append('/Applications/harris/idl88/lib/bridges')
----> 3 from idlpy import *

File /Applications/harris/idl88/lib/bridges/idlpy.py:24
     20 # import traceback
     21 
     22 # Dynamically construct the library name from the Python major.minor version.
     23 idllibrary = "pythonidl" + str(sys.version_info[0]) + str(sys.version_info[1])
---> 24 pyidl = __import__(idllibrary)
     26 # Add IDL's bin directory to the PATH environment variable.
     27 # This is needed so IDL can find the licensing libraries.
     28 idldir = os.path.dirname(pyidl.__file__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythonidl39'
```

I tried to search for a module with the term `*pythonidl*` in directories (both Applications/harris and python), but nothing comes up.

I am trying to use the Python to IDL bridge, but I cannot still make it to work.
Could anyone please help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the directory should point to the path where you installed IDL. Make sure it's the same

Comment: My IDL is installed in the "/Applications/harris/idl88/" directory. So Python can find "idlpy". When I pointed to the wrong directory earlier, python struggled to find idlpy too. So I believe now I am pointing to the right directory. But python still can't find 'pythonidl39'.

Comment: Did you also set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable?